# Deconstructment assignment notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2017-07-19-creating-a-blog-with-gatsby/) example for creating a blog with Gatsby.

Throughout this tutorial, assignment notation is used like so:

```
export default function Index({ data }) {

  const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark

  return (
    <div className="blog-posts">
      {posts
        .filter(post => post.node.frontmatter.title.length > 0)
        .map(({ node: post }) => {
          return (...);
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Line 2, which appears to me as deconstructing assignment, is confusing to me. From what dictionary are we assigning the key `edges`'s value `posts` to? Why are we able to reference `posts` later on without referencing it using the `edges` key?

Comment: It's still a destructuring assignment. All it's doing is _relabelling_ the edges property to "posts". I often do this to make the code more readable if, for example, I'm getting data from an unfamiliar API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stumbled upon destructuring and assigning to a new variable.

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the scroll down to `Assigning to new variable names`.

What it does is that you are giving a declaring a new variable (in your case named `posts` that has the value of `data.allMarkdownRemark.edges`.

The syntax may seem backwards as `edges` is giving value to `posts` and not the other way around, but I think this makes sense if you think about it a bit.

Having it like this allows you to change from this:

`const { edges } = data.allMarkdownRemark`

to this:

`const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark`

with minimal changes.